# How to deal with optional input in shell script?

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, parameter

My assignment task is to print n longest lines from text files. The output is n longest lines with line number and in the same order as in the original file. For example, in the original file:

```
09876543
kbjkbkbbnbnmbnmnmmnbmnbmjbjkb
asjdsakdbakjsdbasbkj
asjdsakdbakjsdbasbkj
asjdsakdbakjsdbasbkj
sa
aaaa
njkasn
k
ppûunsdj
tieutuvi
eee
sdbhsdbjhdsvfdsvfgj
avavdvas
dfsdf
ffdsdfggdgdgdfgdfgdf112233
qwertyuiopsdfghjklxcvbnm,fghjk
```

If n is 10, the output should be

```
2 kbjkbkbbnbnmbnmnmmnbmnbmjbjkb
3 asjdsakdbakjsdbasbkj
4 asjdsakdbakjsdbasbkj
5 asjdsakdbakjsdbasbkj
10 ppûunsdj
11 tieutuvi
13 sdbhsdbjhdsvfdsvfgj
14 avavdvas
16 ffdsdfggdgdgdfgdfgdf112233
17 qwertyuiopsdfghjklxcvbnm,fghjk
```

If n is not assigned, the default number is 5. If there are at least 2 input files, each list of lines is preceded by the corresponding file name. How can I do that? How can I deal with parameter n? 
For example, if parameter n must be entered, this code will work

```
awk '{ print length(), NR, $0 | "sort -rn" }' unix1.txt | head -n 10 | sed 's/[^ ]* //' | sort -n
```

But if n is an optional parameter, this doesn't work. I also don't know how to deal with many files.

```
awk '{ print length(), NR, $0 | "sort -rn" }' unix1.txt | head -n ${$1:-5} | sed 's/[^ ]* //' | sort -n >> temp.txt
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm assuming your pipeline is part of a script that takes a single argument (the number of lines to return).

The parameter expansion `${$1:-5}` is not valid and should be written as `${1:-5}` to make it expand to `5` if `$1` is empty or not set.

Also, your `awk` code invokes `sort` which is a bit obfuscated, in particular because it could easily be inserted in the pipeline as its own stage:

```
awk '{ print length(), NR, $0 }' unix1.txt | 
sort -rn |
head -n "${1:-5}" |
sed 's/[^ ]* //' |
sort -n
```

To simplify it a bit (replace the `sed` with `cut`) and to make the output a bit more "tabular", we can output the intermediate result from `awk` with tabs as the output delimiter:

```
awk -v OFS="\t" '{ print length(), NR, $0 }' unix1.txt | 
sort -rn |
head -n ${1:-5} |
cut -f 2- |
sort -n
```

For the given data, this would output the following for the default number of output lines:

```
2       kbjkbkbbnbnmbnmnmmnbmnbmjbjkb
4       asjdsakdbakjsdbasbkj
5       asjdsakdbakjsdbasbkj
16      ffdsdfggdgdgdfgdfgdf112233
17      qwertyuiopsdfghjklxcvbnm,fghjk
```

To handle multiple files in your script, I would suggest looping over the given filenames.  Maybe something like

```sh
#!/bin/sh

n=${1:-5}
shift

for name do
    if [ "$#" -gt 1 ]; then
        printf 'File: %s\n' "$name"
    fi

    awk -v OFS="\t" '{ print length(), NR, $0 }' "$name" | 
    sort -rn |
    head -n "$n"
    cut -f 2- |
    sort -n
done
```

This script would be invoked as

```
./script.sh 10 file1 file2 file3 etc
```

Note that this *requires* that the first argument always is a number (and that there is nothing `bash`-specific in the script, which is why I use `/bin/sh` as the interpreter). To use proper command line options for giving the number to the script, e.g. as

```
./script -n 10 file1 file2
```

you will have to look into using `getopts` to do command line parsing.  There are plenty of examples of that on this site (you could start by looking at the [getopts](/questions/tagged/getopts) tag).

Comment: `for name; do` is missing a semi? And arent those pipes missing line continuations?

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Neither are needed.