# How to correctly identify the order of parameters?

Tags: bash, shell, arguments, getopts

This is my assignment. The task is to output n longest lines from the input file(s). If there is no argument for n, the the default of value n is 5. If there is no files in the parameter, the standard input is used. If there are at least 2 files, output the name files. The output lines should be in the same order as in the original files. I've asked a question here to deal with the optional arguments: [How to deal with optional input in shell script?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/531130/how-to-deal-with-optional-input-in-shell-script)

However, I'm stuck with another problem with the new shell script.

```
#!/bin/sh
while getopts “n” arg; do
  case $arg in
  n)
    # Check next positional parameter
    eval nextopt=\${$OPTIND}
    # existing or starting with dash?
    if [[ -n $nextopt && $nextopt != -* ]] ; then
      OPTIND=$((OPTIND + 1))
      level=$nextopt
    else
      level=5
    fi
    ;;
  esac
done

for name do
    if [ "$#" -gt 1 ]; then
        printf 'File: %s\n' "$name"
    fi
awk '{ print length(), NR, $0 | "sort -rn" }' $name | head -n $level | sed 's/[^ ]* //' | sort -n

done
```

I run it like this

```
sh ex1.sh -n 10 unix1.txt unix1.1.txt
```

and this is the output

```
File: -n
awk: can't open file -n
 source line number 1
File: 10
awk: can't open file 10
 source line number 1
File: unix1.txt
2 kbjkbkbbnbnmbnmnmmnbmnbmjbjkb
3 asjdsakdbakjsdbasbkj
4 asjdsakdbakjsdbasbkj
5 asjdsakdbakjsdbasbkj
10 ppûunsdj
11 tieutuvi
13 sdbhsdbjhdsvfdsvfgj
14 avavdvas
16 ffdsdfggdgdgdfgdfgdf112233
17 qwertyuiopsdfghjklxcvbnm,fghjk
File: unix1.1.txt
1 csdkbfsdk
2 fskjfnjkfnkjdsndjks
3 fsnjfnsjkf
4 snjfndsjknskjdfbnjksfdsfn
5 323124
6 jknjkkjnk4n4jn2
7 kjnjkb423
13 423b2j3kb4jk23bkb234kb32
14 234jb32jk43b
15 331
```

"-n" and "10" are not files. Also if I run like this

```
sh ex1.sh -n unix1.txt unix1.1.txt
```

The output should be 5 longest lines from the files, but instead:

```
File: -n
head: illegal line count -- unix1.txt
awk: can't open file -n
 source line number 1
File: unix1.txt
head: illegal line count -- unix1.txt
File: unix1.1.txt
head: illegal line count -- unix1.txt
```

So how can I fix this?
Although this is not the goal, this would work

```
while getopts “n” arg; do
  case $arg in
  n)
    # Check next positional parameter
    eval nextopt=\${$OPTIND}
    # existing or starting with dash?
    if [[ -n $nextopt && $nextopt != -* ]] ; then
      OPTIND=$((OPTIND + 1))
      level=$nextopt
    else
      level=5
    fi
    ;;
  esac
done

awk '{ print length(), NR, $0 | "sort -rn" }' unix1.txt | head -n $level | sed 's/[^ ]* //' | sort -n
```

if I run

```
sh ex1.sh -n
```

I've got

```
2 kbjkbkbbnbnmbnmnmmnbmnbmjbjkb
4 asjdsakdbakjsdbasbkj
5 asjdsakdbakjsdbasbkj
16 ffdsdfggdgdgdfgdfgdf112233
17 qwertyuiopsdfghjklxcvbnm,fghjk
```

or

```
sh ex1.sh -n 10
```

and I've got

```
2 kbjkbkbbnbnmbnmnmmnbmnbmjbjkb
3 asjdsakdbakjsdbasbkj
4 asjdsakdbakjsdbasbkj
5 asjdsakdbakjsdbasbkj
10 ppûunsdj
11 tieutuvi
13 sdbhsdbjhdsvfdsvfgj
14 avavdvas
16 ffdsdfggdgdgdfgdfgdf112233
17 qwertyuiopsdfghjklxcvbnm,fghjk
```

which are correct. Also, how to deal with 'If there is no files in the parameter, the standard input is used' ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `-n` option takes an argument, so you need `getopts 'n:' arg`.

The option argument is found in `$OPTARG`.

Don't touch `OPTIND` in the `while getopts` loop.

After the loop, `shift "$(( OPTIND - 1 ))"`.  This leaves the filenames in the positional parameters.

That is,

```sh
#!/bin/sh

level=5
while getopts 'n:' arg; do
    case $arg in
      n) level=$OPTARG ;;
      *) echo 'Error in command line parsing' >&2
    esac
done

shift "$(( OPTIND - 1 ))"

for name do
    # stuff
done
```

Next, you never handle the case of no input files.

The following makes the script use standard input as a filename if there are none given:

```sh
if [ "$#" -eq 0 ]; then
    # handle no filenames, for example:
    set -- /dev/stdin
fi

for name do
     # stuff
done
```

I'll leave the rest to you (but I would strongly suggest moving the `sort` out of `awk` and instead run that as its own stage in the pipeline, for clarity).

Comment: The question does state "If there is no argument for n, the the default of value n is 5.", so you can't enforce that `-n` takes an argument.

Comment: @glennjackman So the script may be called with `-n` and no argument? I read it as "if the number is not given with `-n` (i.e., the option and its argument are missing), it should default to 5".  If you want to read it _strictly_, you don't know what to do if `-n` is not given at all.

Comment: @amV, Kusalananda is right. His code uses the default value when *you don't provide the -n option*, but if you use -n you *must* provide an argument.

Comment: An optional option argument does not make sense. No standard tool behaves like that.  The _option_ may be optional, but if you use it, you _must_ give an argument to it. Trying to do something else is just weird.

Answer (score 2):

> If there is no argument for n, the the default of value n is 5.

You might want to use `getopt` not `getopts`. It's not a bash builtin, so read its man page and look at [the example code](https://salsa.debian.org/debian/util-linux/blob/master/misc-utils/getopt-parse.bash)

Given this sample script

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

tmp=$(getopt -o n:: --long n:: -- "$@")

if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]; then 
    echo "usage: ..." >&2
    exit 1
fi

eval set -- "$tmp"

n=0

while :; do
    case "$1" in
        -n|--n) n=${2:-5}; shift 2 ;;
        --)     shift; break ;;
        *)      echo "error" >&2; exit 1 ;;
    esac
done

echo "n = $n"
echo "remaining args:"
printf "%s\n" "$@"
```

The double colon indicates the option takes an optional argument.
See what happens when it's called various ways:

```
$ bash sample.sh foo bar
n = 0
remaining args:
foo
bar
$ bash sample.sh -n foo bar
n = 5
remaining args:
foo
bar
$ bash sample.sh -n 10 foo bar
n = 5
remaining args:
10
foo
bar
$ bash sample.sh -n10 foo bar
n = 10
remaining args:
foo
bar
$ bash sample.sh --n foo bar
n = 5
remaining args:
foo
bar
$ bash sample.sh --n 10 foo bar
n = 5
remaining args:
10
foo
bar
$ bash sample.sh --n=10 foo bar
n = 10
remaining args:
foo
bar
$ bash sample.sh --n= foo bar
n = 5
remaining args:
foo
bar
```

Read the man page carefully:

> A  simple  short  option  is  a '`-`' followed by a short option character.  If the
>          option has a required argument, it may be written directly after the option char-
>          acter  or  as  the  next  parameter (i.e., separated by whitespace on the command
>          line).  **If the option has an optional argument, it must be written directly after
>          the option character if present**.
>
> A long option normally begins with '`--`' followed by the long option name.  If the
>          option  has a required argument, it may be written directly after the long option
>          name, separated by '`=`', or as the next argument (i.e., separated by whitespace on
>          the  command  line).   **If the option has an optional argument, it must be written
>          directly after the long option name, separated by '`=`',** if present (if you add the
>          '`=`'  but nothing behind it, it is interpreted as if no argument was present; this
>          is a slight bug, see the BUGS).